# Static Lists.transform marked as error but Collections.transform using same variables works

Tags: java, arraylist, guava, jooq

I am trying to create an ArrayList based on a jooq Record class using Guava static Collections2.transform and Lists.transform methods. Below is the query that is producing the result3 Record.

```
    final Table<Record3<Key<Store>, Key<Campaign>, String>> c1 = sql.dsl()
            .select(CAMPAIGN.STORE_KEY, CAMPAIGN.CAMPAIGN_KEY, tag)
            .from(CAMPAIGN)
            .where(CAMPAIGN.CAMPAIGN_KEY.equal(campaignKey))
            .asTable("c1");

    final Table<Record3<Key<Store>, Key<Campaign>, String>> c2 = sql.dsl()
            .select(CAMPAIGN.STORE_KEY, CAMPAIGN.CAMPAIGN_KEY, tag)
            .from(CAMPAIGN)
            .asTable("c2");

    final Result<Record2<Key, Integer>> result3 = sql.dsl()
            .select(c1Campaign, count(c2Tag))
            .from(c1, c2)
            .where(c1.field("tag", String.class).equal(c2.field("tag", String.class)))
            .and(c1.field("store_key", Key.class).equal(c2.field("store_key", Key.class)))
            .and(c1.field("campaign_key", Key.class).notEqual(c2.field("campaign_key", Key.class)))
            .groupBy(c2.field("campaign_key", Key.class))
            .orderBy(inline(2).desc())
            .fetch();
```

Previously I had the following code which was working fine until I realized I needed to add values to the collection later which is not supported by the collection object that is created.

```
    final Collection<Key<Campaign>> keys = Collections2.transform(result3, Record2::value1);
```

Because of this issue I tried to switch to creating an ArrayList but when I add the following I get an error saying "Non-static method cannot be referenced from static context"

```
    final ArrayList<Key<Campaign>> keys2 = Lists.transform(result3, Record2::value1);
```

The confusing thing is both transform methods are static and they are operating on the exact same object so why would the first one work and not the other?  Also how can I accomplish generating an ArrayList in this way if the second method does not work?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered there was a second error I saw on compilation that pointed me to the answer.  Instead of creating an ArrayList from the Lists.transform I changed it to List and it compiles correctly

Answer (score 0):

Couple basic things you need to know about Java and Guava before actually dealing with the question:

1. In Java, `List<Key>` is not `ArrayList<Key>` (but the opposite is true) - `ArrayList` is an **implementation** (one of many possible) of an interface `List`.
2. You can't assign `List` to `ArrayList` (at least without casting, but it's not the solution nor the option here).
3. Even though you create `ArrayList`, it's not the best practice to use concrete implementation in your code, but rather stick to interface (here: `List`).
4. Guava's `Collections2.transform` and `Lists.transform` return **lazy views** of collections you used to create the view ([from javadoc](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform(java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function)), emphasis mine):

   > **The returned list is a transformed view of fromList**; changes to fromList will be reflected in the returned list and vice versa.
   >   (...)
   >
   > **The function is applied lazily, invoked when needed. This is necessary for the returned list to be a view**, but it means that the function will be applied many times for bulk operations like List.contains(java.lang.Object) and List.hashCode(). For this to perform well, function should be fast. To avoid lazy evaluation when the returned list doesn't need to be a view, copy the returned list into a new list of your choosing.

Having all that said, `keys` in your case won't evaluate anything until copied to some collection / list or consumed, so valid approach would be:

```
final Collection<Key<Campaign>> keys = Collections2.transform(result3, Record2::value1);
// later:
final List<Key<Campaign>> keys2 = new ArrayList<>(keys); // here the function is applied
```

or

```
final List<Key<Campaign>> keys2 = new ArrayList<>(Lists.transform(result3, Record2::value1));
```

What bothers me is that you use method references (`Record2::value1`) which indicates you're already using Java 8. If you do, please use [Streams API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```
List<Key<Campaign>> keys = result3.stream()
    .map(Record2::value1)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```